# Multiple hosts in the same cacti graph?

Tags: cacti, rrdtool

I can make this graph on the command prompt using the rrdtool but I cannot make it in Cacti front end as I cannot get the two defs pointing to the two different rrd files.  Is this even possible?

```
/bin/rrdtool graph - \
--imgformat=PNG \
--start=-86400 \
--end=-300 \
--title='Temperature Sensor - Server Closet' \
--base=1000 \
--height=120 \
--width=500 \
--alt-autoscale-max \
--lower-limit=0 \
--vertical-label='Degrees Celsius' \
--slope-mode \
--font TITLE:12: \
--font AXIS:8: \
--font LEGEND:10: \
--font UNIT:8: \
DEF:a="/opt/intranet/cacti/rra/temperature_sensor_server_closet_temp_279.rrd":server_closet_temp:AVERAGE \
LINE1:a#000000FF:"Wayne -  "  \
GPRINT:a:LAST:"Current\:%8.2lf %s"  \
GPRINT:a:MIN:"Min\:%8.2lf %s"  \
GPRINT:a:MAX:"Max\:%8.2lf %s\n" \
DEF:b="/opt/intranet/cacti/rra/stuart_temperature_sensor_server_closet_temp_284.rrd":server    _closet_temp:AVERAGE \
LINE1:b#6DC8FEFF:"Stuart -  "  \
GPRINT:b:LAST:"Current\:%8.2lf %s"  \
GPRINT:b:MIN:"Min\:%8.2lf %s"  \
GPRINT:b:MAX:"Max\:%8.2lf %s\n"
```

This works fine when I generate it on command line by redirecting it to stdout to make the file.  However, in the Cacti interface, I don't see how I can add the second host, since the data source is technically the same, just different host.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Aggregate plugin is designed to do exactly this.

But manually: create a new graph in graph management. Don't select a graph template. Fill in the title and any other graph-global settings you want to change. Then choose Add under Graph Items, pick the host, and the data template. You should have a pick list of all the matching data source in the Data Source dropdown. Change the graph item settings as necessary, and do the same with the other one.

It's much easier with Aggregate though!